# Quartz Drawing with Textures

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I would like to draw without open gl but use textures. I have tried this but whenever I draw with the texture as the line color it gives hard edges as it would normally be. How to I allow the natural ruff edge(I have a ruff texture)? I would like it be like the ones from sketchbook pro.

Thank You.

[image]

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"texture"];

UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

[image]
[image: the texture has a transparent background... I made it black so you could see it.]

Comment: I would suggest you to add a sample image for explaining your issue. As it stands, at least to me, your question makes little to no sense. How is a ruff edge different from a hard edge?

Comment: Try to understand it now I think it makes more sense.

Comment: it still is a bit unclear to me what your issue is. Is it the border of your strokes or is is the fact that your texture is not seamless, hence shows harsh cuts whenever repeating itself. In other words, is the problem you see located within the stroke or at its edges?

Comment: the edges not the tiling problem. well both

Comment: Are you deliberately being vague and contradict?

Comment: Please explain I just want it took look like the image above with all the different textures.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is hard to understand.  Your image of the stroked line has smooth edges, which is the opposite of a hard edge (I think).

Maybe you mean that the interior of the stroked line is tiled with your "texture", and the seams between the tiles are visible.  The problem is that your texture is not tile-able.  The left edge of your texture needs to match up with the right edge, so that when you place two copies side-by-side, the seam becomes invisible.  The top edge needs to match up with the bottom edge for the same reason.

This is not a problem with how you are drawing the texture.  This is a problem with the texture.  You need to create a tileable texture.  If you are using an image editor (like Photoshop) to create your texture, you can find many tutorials on the web about creating repeating or tileable textures.

Comment: Judging from the sample image given, that would also have been my best guess. Nice effort on explaining how to achieve seamless textures.

Comment: Can you please provide an example look at my updated question. That is also not the problem I know about that I am trying to get the external edges...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a pattern image with an alpha channel that isn't all 1.0 or 100%.

Comment: Can you please provide an example look at my updated question.